# How to disable background activity behevior when outside activity dialog touch

Tags: android

I have an activity that is using the Theme.Dialog style such that it is a floating window over another activity. However, when I click outside the dialog window (on the background activity), the button on activity start behaviour again. How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by " the button on activity start behaviour again"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead of activity